# How to get a list of all the daemons running?

Tags: daemon

I use one daemon per project (so that when I open the client, they don't share buffers). I'd like to get a list of all the daemons that are running.

I tried using `lsof -c emacs | grep "TYPE=STREAM"` but that doesn't narrow it down sufficiently.

Is there a better way to go about it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not an Emacs question. What's more, it seems OS-specific.

Comment: If the only reason you use separate daemons is so that buffers are not shared, you may want to take a look at [Perspective](https://github.com/nex3/perspective-el).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, on a Unix-like platform, the sockets are located in a directory called `/tmp/emacs1234` where `/tmp` is the value of the environment variable `TMPDIR` (defaulting to `/tmp`) and `1234` is your user ID. So to list daemon sockets, assuming you aren't passing any argument to `emacsclient` other than the daemon name, just list the contents of that directory.

```
ls "${TMPDIR-/tmp}/emacs$(id -u)"
```

On many systems you can get away with just

```
ls /tmp/emacs$UID
```